# $k$-element subsets of $[n]$ that do not contain $2$ consecutive integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $k,n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $k\leq n$. Find the total number of $k$-element selections from $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ that do not contain any 2 consecutive integers

Comment: I have not gotten very far. I'm thinking along the lines of Inclusion/Exclusion, ie $\binom{n}{k} - $sets that have 2 consecutive integers.

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion is going to be pretty ugly here.  Here is a hint: putting $a$ into such a set excludes you from putting $a+1$ into the set.  Can you use this (equivalent) condition to reformulate your problem in terms of tiling a strip of length $n+1$?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out anything with tiling the strip, but what if I treat it as a binary string of length $n$ with $n-k$ $0$s (numbers not chosen). From here I will have $n - k + 1$ "gaps" from which I can choose where to place a $1$, therefore getting $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$.

Comment: That works.  The tilings thing is pretty much the same idea: put a domino over positions $a$ and $a+1$ iff $a\in S$ and squares where dominoes are not; we have a total of $n-k+1$ objects and $k$ of them are dominoes.

Comment: I get it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

It's the same as counting bitstrings of length $n$ containing exactly $k$ ones, no two of them consecutive,

which is the same as counting solutions of $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_k=n-k$ in integers $x_j$ such that $x_0\ge0$, $x_k\ge0$, and $x_j\gt0$ for $0\lt j\lt k$,

which is the same as counting solutions of $y_0+y_1+\cdots+y_k=n+2-k$ in positive integers $y_j$,

which is the same as counting solutions of $z_0+z_1+\cdots+z_k=n+1-2k$ in nonnegative integers $z_j$.

Don't use inclusion-exclusion. It's a simple binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Using generating functions and the binary string of length $n$ with $k$ ones model we need to select the size of the $k+1$ gaps between the ones, where the first and last one may be empty and the inner gaps must have size at least one. This gives
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}\times\frac{z}{1-z}\times\frac{z}{1-z}\times\cdots
\times\frac{z}{1-z}\times\frac{z}{1-z}\times\frac{1}{1-z}.$$
This simplifies to
$$f(z) = \frac{z^{k-1}}{(1-z)^{k+1}}.$$
Now the gaps must add up to $n-k$ so the answer is
$$[z^{n-k}] f(z)
= [z^{n-k}]  \frac{z^{k-1}}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
= [z^{n+1-2k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}.$$
By Newton's binomial series this is
$$\binom{n+1-2k + k}{n+1-2k}
= \binom{n+1-k}{n+1-2k} = \binom{n+1-k}{k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the Fibonacci Sequence! $F_{n+2}$ (where $F_n$ is Fibonacci) will also create this sequence.

Comment: That is how I solved it, now I am just having a problem coming up with the induction proof if anyone can help!