# Decide the total amount of six digit numbers which don't contain the sequence.

Tags: combinatorics

The following problem.

I have to decide how many numbers that satisfy the following

It should not contain the sequence 17 eg. 1743, 4179.

A leading zero does not count as a digit. 0234 is not a four digit number.

My approach was to get all the numbers and then subtract all numbers with 17.

All numbers - Bad numbers

Bad numbers.

17.... = $10^4$

.17... = $8\cdot 10^3$

..17.. = $8\cdot 10^3$

...17. = $8\cdot 10^3$

....17 = $8\cdot 10^3$

Then i tried to remove duplicates. 
Example. Last row contains elements from row 1 - 3.

But it results in bad answer!

Comment: Why are you multiplying by $8$ instead of $9$? Aren't you just trying to exclude the possibility of $0$?

Comment: You're correct. I overcompensated while trying to exclude the leading 0! @NicholasR.Peterson

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we  first compute  the number  of strings of  length $n$  of a
$q$-letter alphabet where  we have at least three  letters, i.e. $q\ge
3$, that do not contain  a given two-letter sequence consisting of two
different  letters,  none of  which  is the zero letter.   This  can  be done  by
inclusion-exclusion and the formula is (this part is by inspection)

$$q^n - \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} q^{n-2k} 
 [z^{n-2k}] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k+1}.$$

This formula  holds because the  sum term counts strings  that contain
$m$ copies of the forbidden sequence exactly

$${m\choose 1} - {m\choose 2} + {m\choose 3}
-\ldots\pm (-1)^{m+1} {m\choose m}
= 1,$$ i.e. once. Here we are working with the gaps between adjacent instances of the forbidden pair, using a technique that was presented in more detail at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603641/k-element-subsets-of-n-that-do-not-contain-2-consecutive-integers).

Simplifying the formula we obtain
$$q^n - \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} q^{n-2k} {n-2k + k\choose k}
= q^n + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
(-1)^k q^{n-2k} {n-k\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
(-1)^k q^{n-2k} {n-k\choose k}.$$

To get a closed form of this sum we introduce the generating function
$f(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} f_n z^n$ where $f_n$ is our sum to get
$$f(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} z^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
(-1)^k q^{n-2k} {n-k\choose k}
= \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k q^{-2k} 
\sum_{n\ge 2k} {n-k\choose k} z^n q^n.$$

This yields
$$\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k q^{-2k} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+k\choose k} z^{n+2k} q^{n+2k}
= \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k z^{2k} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+k\choose k} z^n q^n
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k z^{2k} 
\left(\frac{1}{1-qz}\right)^{k+1}
= \left(\frac{1}{1-qz}\right) \frac{1}{1+z^2/(1-qz)}
= \frac{1}{1-qz+z^2}.$$

Now the roots of the  denominator of this rational generating function
are $$\rho_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}q \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{q^2-4}$$
which implies that $$f_n = c_1 \rho_1^{-n} + c_2 \rho_2^{-n}.$$
Actually computing $c_{1,2}$ we get
$$c_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2} \mp \frac{1}{2} q \frac{1}{\sqrt{q^2-4}}$$
so that
$$c_{1,2} = \mp \frac{1}{\rho_{1,2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{q^2-4}}$$
and thus we obtain by using that $\rho_1 \rho_2 = 1$ the result
$$f_n = 
c_1 \rho_2^n + 
c_2 \rho_1^n
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{q^2-4}}
\left(-\frac{\rho_2^n}{\rho_1} + \frac{\rho_1^n}{\rho_2} \right)
\\ =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{q^2-4}}
\left(\rho_1^{n+1} - \rho_2^{n+1} \right) .$$

When $q=3$ we obtain the sequence
$$  3, 8, 21, 55, 144, 377, 987, 2584, 6765, 17711,\ldots$$ 
which is [OEIS A001906](https://oeis.org/A001906) .

For  $q=10$ we obtain the sequence
$$10, 99, 980, 9701, 96030, 950599, 9409960,
 93149001, 922080050, 9127651499,\ldots $$
which is [OEIS A004189](https://oeis.org/A004189) .

Now  the  original  problem   does  not  admit  strings  with  leading
zeros. Therefore the answer is given by
$$f_{n+1,10} - f_{n, 10}$$
which yields
$$89, 881, 8721, 86329, 854569, 8459361, 83739041,\\
 828931049, 8205571449, 81226783441,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A072256](https://oeis.org/A072256).

**Addendum I.**  By the  looks of the  OEIS entries, this  solution is
probably more involved than it  needs to be.  The reader is encouraged
to look for this kind of simple solution.

**Addendum II.** When $q=2$ the generating function becomes
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-2z+z^2} = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$
so that $$f_{n, 2} = n+1.$$
This is obvious as the forbidden sequence say it is $10$ forbids a run containing a one followed by a zero. Therefore we can only have sequences consisting of at most two runs, a string of zeros followed by a string of ones. There are $n+1$ of these.

Answer (score 1):

Here    is   a   very    simple   solution    that   does    not   use
inclusion-exclusion.  The  setup  is  the  same  as  in  the  previous
answer.  Suppose  the forbidden  two-letter  pattern  consists of  two
different letters.

Introduce  the  sequence $\{a_n\}$  that  counts  all  strings of  $n$
letters without the forbidden pattern  that end in the first letter of
the  pattern  and  the   sequence  $\{b_n\}$  that  counts  admissible
sequences that do not end   in said letter. The  quantity  $$a_n+b_n$$
gives the value we are looking for.

Then  we  have  $a_0  =  0$  and  $b_0 =  1$  and  the  following  two
recurrences:
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_n = (q-2) a_{n-1} + (q-1) b_{n-1}.$$
This is because an admissible sequence on $n$ letters that ends in the first letter call it $P$ of the pattern can be obtained from a sequence on $n-1$ letters of the same type by appending $P$ (recall that we said the two letters in the pattern are different) or by taking a sequence that does not end in $P$ and appending $P$. On the other hand an admissible sequence on $n$ letters that does not end in $P$ can be obtained from those that end in $P$ by appending any letter but $P$ and $Q$, where $Q$ is the second letter of the pattern or appending any letter but $P$ to a sequence on $n-1$ letters that does not end in $P.$

Introducing the two generating functions
$$A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$$

and multiplying by $z^n$ and summing over $n\ge 1$ we obtain the two
equations 
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n z^n = 
z \sum_{n\ge 1} a_{n-1} z^{n-1} +  z \sum_{n\ge 1} b_{n-1} z^{n-1}$$
and
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} b_n z^n = 
(q-2) z \sum_{n\ge 1} a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + (q-1) z \sum_{n\ge 1} b_{n-1} z^{n-1} $$
or alternatively (using the intial values)
$$A(z) - 0 = z A(z) + z B(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) - 1 = (q-2) z A(z) + (q-1) z B(z).$$

Solving these we find that
$$A(z) = \frac{z}{1-qz+z^2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \frac{1-z}{1-qz+z^2}.$$

Now  the  generating function  $f(z)$  of  all  sequences without  the
forbidden pattern is

$$f(z) = A(z) + B(z) = \frac{1}{1-qz+z^2}$$

the same as we obtained earlier and we may continue on as before.

**Observation.** This generating function does not take into account that there may not be any leading zeros. To get that value, take the difference between consecutive values as shown in the other answer.