# Number of subsets without consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $S=\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$. Let $X$ denote the number of subsets of $S$ of four elements which contain no consecutive numbers.

The claim is that $X$ equals the coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $\dfrac{x^6}{(1-x)^5}$. How would I prove this?

Comment: The number of such subsets is given by ${15-4+1 \choose 4}$.

Comment: By the way, I think there is a typo in your question. I'm fairly certain that there is no $x^{14}$ term in that expression.

Comment: So that would mean there are $396$ subsets. And you're right, there is no $x^{14}$ term. That is the way it is presented to me though. Doesn't seem it equals the coefficient of $x^1$ or $x^4$.. I'll contact my professor, looks like he did something wrong.

Comment: @JosephZambrano : Why would you say there is no $x^{14}$ term?  Remeber that $\dfrac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$, and there are terms of all degrees in $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  Raise that to the $5$th power, getting $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^5}$, then multiply by $x^6$, and you'll find terms of all degrees in $\{6,7,8,\ldots\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about that. However, I could calculate the answer that way, but I believe the question is to give an heuristic argument.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but: $y^2\sum_{n=k}^\infty {n\choose k} y^{n+2} = \frac{y^{k+2}}{(1-y)^{k+1}}. $

Comment: @MichaelHardy How I missed that I do not know... thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas In general, for $\{1,2,...,n\}$ the number of such $k$-subsets is given by ${n-k+1 \choose k}$.

Comment: @JosephZambrano, you have stated the formula $\binom{n - k + 1}{k}$ (without a hint of a proof) several times now. Care to expand?

Comment: $[x^{14}] x^6 (1 - x)^{-5} = [x^8] (1 - x)^{-5} = (-1)^8 \binom{-5}{8} = \binom{8 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = 495$

Comment: @vonbrand http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603641/k-element-subsets-of-n-that-do-not-contain-2-consecutive-integers

Comment: @JosephZambrano, Marko Riedel's answer gives what OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Call the elements of your subset $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_2$, $a_4$ in order. Your restrictions translate into:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= a_1 \ge 1 \\
x_2 &= a_2 - a_1 \ge 2 \\
x_3 &= a_3 - a_2 \ge 2 \\
x_4 &= a_4 - a_3 \ge 2 \\
x_5 &= 15 - a_4  \ge 0
\end{align}
The definitons amount to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 15$. Set up generating functions for each $x_i$ variable:
\begin{align}
x_1:                   &\quad z + z^2 + \cdots = \frac{z}{1 - z} \\
x_2 \text{ to } x_4: &\quad z^2 + z^3 + \cdots = \frac{z^2}{1 - z} \\
x_5:                   &\quad 1 + z + \cdots     = \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}
Multiplying all, and remembering we want the term whose exponent is 15:
\begin{align}
[z^{15}] \frac{z^7}{(1 - z)^5}
   &= [z^8] (1 - z)^{-5} \\
   &= \binom{-5}{8} (-1)^8 \\
   &= 495
\end{align}